# Hide the top bar on an Android device with Xamarin used by Monogame

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, monogame

I have a problem with my android device when I develop with Monogame.
I cannot remove the status bar above my device. So I have a white display part. Not the status bar but a white display part.
The below bar does not appear as I expected but not the top bar.
I know it is possible but maybe not with Monogame Framework.
Thanks for your help.[image][image]

Comment: Open your `MainActivity`, put this line, `Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
            Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.ForceNotFullscreen);` in your `OnCreate` method.